We could not find a Google Tag Manager container ID on the home page of your site. Nextjs third parties library
i tried to link my website ( My Website ) to google tag manager using next js third parties library.
layout page code :
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="ar" dir="rtl">
      <GoogleTagManager gtmId="GTM-K7Z75CQN"/>
      <body className={`${tajawal.className} bg-slate-50`}>
        <DataProvider>
          <NextTopLoader />
          <Header />
          <Navbar />
          <main>{children}</main>
          <Footer />
          <Toaster />
        </DataProvider>
        <SpeedInsights />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

and when i try to verify my website on google search console i get this message : We could not find a Google Tag Manager container ID on the home page of your site.
i also tried using this method for linking :
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="ar" dir="rtl">
      <Head>
        <script
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: `(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-K7Z75CQN');`,
          }}
        />
      </Head>
      <body className={`${tajawal.className} bg-slate-50`}>
        <DataProvider>
          <NextTopLoader />
          <Header />
          <Navbar />
          <main>{children}</main>
          <Footer />
          <Toaster />
        </DataProvider>
        <SpeedInsights />
        <noscript dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: `
            <iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-K7Z75CQN"
            height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
            `,
          }}></noscript>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

but i get this message : The Google Tag Manager snippet on your site is in the wrong location on the page
